# Linking federated user to local B2C user through email address

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I'm working on a proof of concept hooking up a SaaS application with Azure B2C. The out of the box user flows all work nicely but really don't deliver the functionality that I require. So welcome for the [azure-ad-b2c](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/link-local-account-with-federated-account) samples to guide om on creating custom policies that allow me to get the job done, up to a point. I also read a good blog post series from [@rbrayb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9922/rbrayb) f.e. [link-local-account-with-federated-account](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/linking-a-federated-login-against-an-existing-azure-ad-b2c-local-account-ea2db2fc2252) (thanks for those) which gave me a lot of information and a [policy](https://gist.github.com/rbrayb/536431c478f89d3c6d5ab39fbc26e8a7) to start with.

Here comes the tricky part, at least for me :

First :
The thing is that I am writing a multi-tenant SaaS application that will have a predefined (and configured) set of identity providers (AZureAD, Google, Auth0). Tenants will need to be able to use multiple IDP's because of collaboration within the application.

So, is there a way to have these policies redirect users to their IDP based on their email address using a domain hint or something?

Second: the policy relies on de external IDP oid claim to match the external and local created user. Though, in my scenario, it's possible that through user invitation from the application, this oid is unknown at the time of local user creation. I would like to use the email address to link the user. I tried altering some PartnerClaimType's but to no avail.

```
<OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid"/>
    .
    .
    .
</OutputClaims>
```

So, Any direction on which claim transformations to alter?

Thanks for reading and I hope to get some guidance!

Comment: I've implemented the first question in the past with a screen that only asks for the user email, then calls a REST endpoint to figure out the IdP to use (or "local"). It is also possible to map domains to IdPs in the policy XML itself, but that will require updating it. Not sure about the domain_hint, could be possible. For the second scenario, you could use some extension attribute on the user where you store e.g. the invitation ID, then you'd need a REST endpoint to actually look up the user by that ID, and then add the identity to them with the actual object ID.

Comment: On a side note, please keep in mind account harvesting attacks, if you have a login screen and enter `supersniper39@outlook.com` and it takes you to sign in on the `joe.jones@contoso.com` federated tenant then it is an indicator that the account exists in your system and you've just exposed PII. If the user wants to sign-in with local let them sign in with local, if they want to sign-in with contoso let them sign in with contoso, it'll be the same B2C Object ID so what's the harm.

Comment: bolt-io, Thanks for pointing out the account harvesting, will need to look into that. in response to the 'harm' of the local login is that most of the time users will reside in Azure AD. If they are not eligible to use the application from a certain point in time, when f.e. the user is no longer employed, access should be revoked. Allowing local accounts circumvents that principle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two samples to implement the email address part; [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/default-home-realm-discovery) and [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/home-realm-discovery-modern).

You should use issuerUserId and:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" PartnerClaimType="iss" />
```

But the IDP may have different names for these in the mapping i.e. "oid" and "iss".

They may not even exist!

Also there is a limit on the number of items in the identityProvider StringCollection. I think it's around 5?